# Ebean: How to correctly select rows where values?

Tags: java, sql, playframework, ebean

I have a question concerning Ebean. Unfortunately I cannot find any documentation to help me. I would like to select all rows where a value is true and where all members of a OneToMany relationship also have a value which is true.

Here is an example:

```
@Entity
public class Book extends Model {
  @Id
  public Long id;
  public Boolean isAvailable;

  public static Finder<Long, Book> find = new Finder<>(Long.class, Book.class);
}
```

I would like to complete the findAllByIsAvailable method:

```
@Entity
public class Category extends Model {
  @Id
  public Long id;
  public Boolean isAvailable;
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="category", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
  public List<Book> books;

  public static Finder<Long, Category> find = new Finder<>(Long.class, Category.class);

  public static List<Category> findAllByIsAvailable() {
    // Find all categories where isAvailable == true and books.isAvailable == true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to add a `@ManyToOne` relationship to your `Book` class as :

```
@Entity
public class Book extends Model {
  @Id
  public Long id;
  public Boolean isAvailable;

  @ManyToOne
  public Category category;

  public static Finder<Long, Book> find = new Finder<>(Long.class, Book.class);
}
```

Then you will be able to insert in your `findAllByIsAvailable()` function this

```
return Category.find.fetch("books").where().eq("isAvailable",true).eq("books.isAvailable",true).findList();
```

`.fetch("books")` means that you make a left join of two tables.

You can read a lot about Ebean here http://www.avaje.org/doc/ebean-userguide.pdf
There also are some examples.